# Apply font for certain string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a "$" symbol in my app. And I want this char to apply a custom font in every string that contains this symbol. I know that font is related to UILabel but can I relate it to string? Is it possible to make it once and automate it?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.  There is no way to automate that.

Essentially what you would have to do is set the `attributedText` property of the UILabel with an NSAttributedString that applied the correct style settings to symbol when it was found.

So you might create a function that takes a string and creates an NSAttributed string for it with your desired font settings wherever the symbol is found.  Then you could add a method to UILabel to accept a string, pass it through your function, and set the attributedText of the label

But it's going to take some work on your part.